# Tower of Hanoi - First Move

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I know the minimum moves the Tower of Hanoi can generate is 2^n - 1 given n pegs. Suppose we have 3 positions, A, B and C and all pegs start from A and the goal is to move the pegs from A to C and no peg is smaller than the one under.

In the Python and Java code online, it seems when n is odd, the first peg is moved to C and when n is even, the first peg is moved to B.

Does anyone know it is the case? Why not when n is odd, move first peg to B instead?

Thanks!

Comment: If you read the code and think about how the recursion works you should see why the finishing peg alternates depending on the number of disks.

Comment: Assume that you are trying to move from A to C.  As @EthanBolker indicated, compare the parity (odd or even) of the number of disks with the parity (odd or even) of whether you start directly from A to C (analogizes to odd parity) or start from A to B (making A to C analogize to even parity).

Comment: It is possible to solve this yourself, without reading code written by someone else.  Why not try?

Comment: With optimal solutions, you move the smallest disk in alternate moves so a total of $2^{n-1}$ times either $A,B,C,A,B,C,A,\ldots$ or  $A,C,B,A,C,B,A,\ldots$.  You want to end up on $C$ after its $2^{n-1}$th move so either $1$ less than a multiple of $3$ or $1$ more than a multiple of $3$ depending on the parity of $n$

Comment: Hi All, sorry I have been thinking about this question the past 2 days but still have no clue. I am thinking would it be okay if I had two proofs: one complete induction proof for n being even and another complete induction proof for n being odd? Thanks!